# SOLIDITY Error: Error encoding arguments

Tags: solidity

[image]So i am getting this error: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid address (argument="address", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.1.0) (argument=null, value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.1.2).

Im basically copying other contract so i don't understand whats happening. I already tried the exact code of an already lauched coin and still getting this error.

Comment: What are you doing to cause the error? e.g. deploying the contract, calling a method, .. Please include the code as text to make it easier to answer.

Comment: It seems the error message is coming due to the issues in the address. The address has to be provided with quotes. It must be double qutoes "". It is not going to work with single qutoes.